# Django, saving image, OSError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, django, file

**CODE:**

```
if request.is_ajax():
    testpic = TestPic.objects.get(pk=1)

    form = TestPicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        from PIL import Image
        from io import BytesIO

        data = request.FILES['file']
        data_50 = request.FILES['file']

        input_file = BytesIO(data.read())
        image_crop = Image.open(input_file)
        print('print 2')

        # Problem starts.
        input_file_50 = BytesIO(data_50.read())
        image_crop_50 = Image.open(input_file_50)
        image_crop = image_crop.crop((1,1,100,100))
        image_crop_50 = image_crop_50.crop((40, 40, 140, 140))
        image_resize = image_crop.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image_resize_50 = image_crop_50.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        image_file = BytesIO()
        image_resize.save(image_file, 'JPEG')

        image_file_50 = BytesIO()
        image_resize_50.save(image_file_50, 'JPEG')

        data.file = image_file
        testpic.file = data

        data_50.file = image_file_50
        testpic.file_50 = data_50

        testpic.save()
        return JsonResponse({'success': 'file_uploaded'})

    return JsonResponse({'success': 'failed'})
```

And Traceback is like this:

```
print 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
... I remove some lines ...
  File "D:\pythonDev\project\upward\chatkaboo\authapp\views.py", line 844, in crop
    image_crop_50 = Image.open(input_file_50)
  File "D:\pythonDev\interpreters\forMultichat\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2590, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000024B40510BF8>
```

**Description:**

As you can see on above my code's purpose is that saving requested image file.

I tried to find what happened and which line has problem. So `print 2` was printed, and therefore `input_file_50 = BytesIO(data_50.read())` line has problem.

**Question:**

Why this error happened? `BytesIO` can only deal with just one file at a time?

How can I deal with a file and save it as two or more files?

Comment: First guess: after `data.read()` you should do `data.seek(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @wiesion said in a comment to the question, you could try to reset the buffer with `data.seek(0)`.

Why? Well, in your code you have this

```
data = request.FILES['file']
data_50 = request.FILES['file']
```

meaning that `data` and `data_50` will point to the same file. When you call `data.read()`, the content gets read and the current position stays at the end of the file.

When you later call `data_50.read()`, the current position is already at the end (because its the same file as `data`) and there is no more content to be read, so the call to `read()` returns no content. So there is no image to be saved.

By calling `data.seek(0)` (or `data_50.seek(0)` or `request.FILES['file'].seek(0)`) you are telling that file to place the current position at the start of the file again, so that a next call to `read()` can output the whole file content again.

```
input_file = BytesIO(data.read())
image_crop = Image.open(input_file)
print('print 2')

# ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR CODE
# it modifies the 'data' object, which is the same as 'data_50'
data.seek(0)

# Problem starts.
input_file_50 = BytesIO(data_50.read())
image_crop_50 = Image.open(input_file_50)
```

---

Another way you could try (without calling `.seek(0)`) would be to assing the result of `.read()` to a variable:

```
file_content = request.FILES['file'].read()
input_file = BytesIO(file_content)
input_file_50 = BytesIO(file_content)

image_crop = Image.open(input_file)
image_crop_50 = Image.open(input_file_50)
```

Maybe you could try this version and let us know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for good answer. But I have a question, If I use your 'using read()', where can I find or treat line: 'data.file = image_file
        testpic.file = data

        data_50.file = image_file_50
        testpic.file_50 = data_50' ??

Comment: Hm... good point. I'm not exactly sure. But first things first: did you try your code with just adding `data.seek(0)`? Only if that works, then we can continue to look for a way to optimize/improve your code.

Comment: Ok, I tried it but it's throwing `a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'` Is it possible error? or Did I something wrong?

Comment: `input_file = BytesIO(data.seek(0))` this line. Here is traceback: `Traceback (most recent call last):
...removed ...
  File "D:\pythonDev\project\upward\chatkaboo\authapp\views.py", line 840, in crop
    input_file = BytesIO(data.seek(0))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
[2018/06/23 22:19:05] HTTP POST /accounts/crop/ 500 [0.03, 127.0.0.1:53564]
`

Comment: Ah, no, `data.seek(0)` should be its own line. Try just adding that single line to your code; I made an edit to my answer to show where you should place that single line.

Comment: Thanks Ralf. It works. I very appreciate your kind answer.